# Volume of the solid of revolution: $y=x^2$ about $y=x$.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, volume, solid-of-revolution

Question: The region bounded by $y=x^2$ and $y=x$ is rotated about $y=x$. Find the volume of the solid of the revolution.

My answer: I rotated the region $45^\circ$ clockwise and obtained the curve $(x,y)=(\large\frac{t^2+t}{\sqrt2},\frac{t^2-t}{\sqrt2})$ where $0\leq t\leq 1$. Then the volume can be found by the disk method formula:
$$V=\int_0^1\pi y^2dx=\pi\int_0^1\frac{t^2(t-1)^2(2t+1)}{2\sqrt2}dt=\frac{\pi}{30\sqrt2}\approx 0.074.$$

Is my answer correct? Can you give another solution?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to be all correct, you can assure yourself of this my plotting the transformation graphically.

Comment: The $x$ integral should be on $[0,\sqrt2]$. I have assigned this to calculus students to be done using the disks directly orthogonal to $y=x$. It’s a bit trickier, but it works. So does Pappus.